# How to copy dependent executable also to the same folder where the main executable lives while deploying with CQtDeployer?

Tags: c++, deployment, qt5

I will start my question with an example. Suppose I have a qt application named 'MyApp' and there are two dependent executable 'xprintidle' and 'xdotool' . For perfect working of my application I need MyApp, xprintidle and xdotool are to be in same folder after installing.

I am using CQtDeployer to deploy my application. I am using qt installation framework also, so in CQtdeployer i am using -qif option to create my installer directly. But i am not able to copy   xprintidle' and 'xdotool also in to my package.

I am doing this in Ubuntu latest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cqtdeployer -bin MyApp,xprintidle,xdotool
```

This will copy all three in the same folder with MyApp